Additive characters from coarse quotient maps
Let's consider a (finitely generated) group $\Gamma$ and a
coarse quotient map
$q\colon\Gamma\to\mathbb{R}$.
I'm interested in the 1-cocycle
$\sigma\colon\Gamma\to\ell_\infty\Gamma$,
defined by $\sigma(s):= q-s\cdot q$,
where the $\Gamma$-action on $\ell_\infty\Gamma$
is given by $(s\cdot q)(x)=q(s^{-1}x)$.
Let's assume that $\Gamma$ is amenable
and take an (extremal) invariant mean $\nu$.
Then $\ell_\infty\Gamma \subset L^2(\nu)$
and the $\Gamma$-action on $\ell_\infty\Gamma$ extends to a
unitary $\Gamma$-action on $L^2(\nu)$.
Thus we view $\sigma$ as a map into $L^2(\nu)$.
I would expect the answer to the following questions is true.

(1) Is $[\sigma]$ nonzero in
the reduced cohomology $\overline{H^1}(\Gamma,L^2(\nu))$?


(2) Is the additive character $\nu\circ\sigma$ nonzero on $\Gamma$?

Obviously (2) implies (1) and the converse is true for $\Gamma$
with Shalom's property $\mathrm{H}_{\mathrm{T}}$.
The answer to (1) is true if the coarse quotient map $q$
is given by the composition $q=\chi\circ\phi$ of
a coarse isomorphism $\phi$ from $\Gamma$ into
another group $\Lambda$ and an additive
character $\chi\colon\Lambda\to\mathbb{R}$.
See [Y. Shalom; Acta Math., 2004] (doi, zb, mr).
